# How can I store a temporary table from an executed procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-manager

I have the following code:

```
SELECT @Name = [TrigTable] 
FROM [dbo].[setdevelopmentjob] 
WHERE [TrigTable] IS NOT NULL

PRINT @Name

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @Name;

#TriggerTable = EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT * FROM #TriggerTable
```

Obviously the line `#TriggerTable = Exec sp_executesql @sql`is incorrect syntax but it shows what I'm trying to do. The columns are variable, meaning that I can't just declare a table variable. How can I pass the output of this executed procedure to `#TriggerTable`?

Comment: You may want to look at this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246276/sql-server-put-stored-procedure-result-set-into-a-table-variable-without-specif

Comment: use OPENROWSET, best way to treat the results of a stored procedure as a table expression

Comment: Not quite. I've tried these approaches. when you run sp_executesql you can't retrieve any temp tables that are produced from the query

Comment: Didn't any of the answers listed here help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the data in Global temporary table (##) with Select * into approach and to store in #temp table you have to create the table first  which I am aware of while using dynamic sql  But you can certainly do that in run time but still you may need some physical table to access it.

```
create table testtmp (id int, namen varchar(15)) 

--inserting the data into physical table 
insert into testtmp (id, namen)

select 1 as ID, 'XYZ' as namen union all
select 2 as ID, 'ABC' as namen union all
select 3 as ID, 'DIG' as namen

create table #temp (ID int) 

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select ID from testtmp' 
insert into #temp exec sp_executesql @sql 

select * from #temp 

Gives you this output: 

 ID 
  1 
  2 
  3
```

With global temporary table you can do it easily and you don't have to create any tables, you can specify column names if you would like to.

```
 declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * into ##Gloabltmptest from testtmp' 
 exec sp_executesql @sql 

 select * from ##Gloabltmptest
```

Output:

```
 ID  namen
 1  XYZ
 2  ABC
 3  DIG
```

Added table variable as well, similar to #temp tables.

```
declare @table table (IDtab int, nametab varchar(15)) 

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from testtmp' 
insert into @table exec sp_executesql @sql 

select * from @table
```