# How to get column names from a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

Using SQL Server.

I have a very extensive query, with a lot of aliasing, etc...

Is there a way, using just SQL (stored proc is fine, but not PHP, etc), to get a list of all column names from this query? (I realize I will have to probably embed my query inside of this solution but that is fine. Just a temporary measure.)

Thanks!

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS if you want the columns of a base table.

Comment: Unless you are running dynamic sql, list of columns in the result set must be static. Why don't you get them at design time?

Answer (score 28):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or later you can take advantage of [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258(v=sql.110).aspx)

```
SELECT name 
FROM 
sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
('Your Query Here', NULL, 0) ;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2473)

Comment: @IrRelevant there's nothing in the question that indicates to me that the result should be concatenated so your comment confuses me.

Comment: Works like charm.

Comment: This is money. Read through a whole blog post about how to do this with postgres, but this sql trick worked like an absolute charm. Just put your query inside the quotes 'Your Query Here' and voila; the column names from the query result are shown in a table. Beautiful

Comment: I was looking for this for weeks - this is the best way of obtaining the information about the columns involved into a query. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There are various ways that you can get the *columns* out of the query, such as:

```
select top 0 s.*
from (<your query here>) s;
```

Then you can parse the results.

However, I have found another approach useful. Create either a view or a table using the same logic:

```
select top 0 s.*
into _TempTableForColumns
from (<your query here>) s;
```

Then use `information_schema` (or the system tables if you prefer):

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = '_TempTableForColumns' and schema_name = 'dbo';

drop table _TempTableForColumns;
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can get type information along with the column names. But the engine still has to run the query and that might take time even though no rows are returned. Although the column names and types are available after compiling, I am not aware of a way to get them without also executing the query.

Comment: Your first answer returns list of columns with no data but I think OP expecting list of column names in a single row as a result set.

Comment: @Kaf I don't think `get a list of all column names from this query` requires a single row. If it was that's not hard to add in any case See [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/451415/119477)

Comment: @ConradFrix: sorry for my mistake. I meant, `OP expecting column names in a single column` not `a single row`. It's nearly 5:30 here. :(

Comment: @Kaf I see. Well then it's just `Select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns...`

Answer (score 0):

After SQL Server 2008

```
select * 
from sys.columns c 
inner join sys.objects o on c.object_id = o.object_id 
where o.name = 'TableName'
```

Before

```
select * 
from syscolumns c 
inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id 
where o.name = 'TableName'
```

Comment: For Microsoft SQL. Are you talking about what kind of SQL?