# Multi-tables joining in Cursor

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I got a table of words to be searched in the database and the table

## Parameter

```
id     Name              Word
----------------------------------
1      word search       c&a
2      word search       Beton
3      word search       Freiman
4      Anything          Null
```

beside that i have the Procedure SearchAllTable, which is the searching Procedure and for searching the words in the database.

```
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @name varchar(100)
DECLARE @word varchar(100)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, word FROM #Parameter WHERE Name = 'word search'
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id,@word

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
EXEC SearchAllTables @word
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id, @word
END
CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```

the problem that I got the result in multipule tables and I want them all to be listed in one table without any suppuration.

Answer (score 1):

Insert your results into temporary table, created before cursor cycle

**UPDATE**

try this [UNION the results of multiple stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292069/union-the-results-of-multiple-stored-procedures)

Comment: I already tried but for some reasons it is not working 

   'SELECT * INTO #temp FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
  'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',  'EXEC SearchAllTables @word')'

Comment: As i understand you can't modify `SearchAllTables` or rewrite it as function?  Then probably you should ask new question about problem with  `openrowset`. And wait if someone advice something new in that question.  May be this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292069/union-the-results-of-multiple-stored-procedures

Answer (score 0):

Collect your result into a temp table or table variable and get it in a single select outside the cursor. Please try the bellow.

```
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @name varchar(100)
DECLARE @word varchar(100)
--Create Result table wrt your SP output
DECLARE @Result TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(16), DATEVAL DATETIME)


DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, word FROM @Parameter WHERE Name = 'word search'
OPEN cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id,@word

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Result
        EXEC SearchAllTables @word

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id, @word
    END
CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur

--Selecting result as a single unit
SELECT * FROM @Result
```

Comment: It is not working 

An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.